# Get Y-value of a graph in C#

Tags: c#, charts

In C#, how can I get the Y-value of a point of a chart series, knowing its X-value which is of type DateTime? I do not know the index of the series, only know their names.

Below are my codes. In fact I did a simulation of stock prices over time. Now I want to add the series "Service dates" to mark the specific date points of the simulation. What I need now is to set the `colpos` to the Y-value of the series whose name is given by `colinfo.colptf`

Or could you just show me how to get the index of the `chart1.series[colinfo.colptf]`?

```
private void radioButton1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            radioButton2.Checked = false;
            radioButton3.Checked = false;
            radioButton4.Checked = false;
            clearseries(chart1, "Service dates");
            chart1.Series.Add("Service dates");
            chart1.Series["Service dates"].Color = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series["Service dates"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
            foreach (var simul in simulations)
                foreach (var colinfo in simul.VPdates)
                {
                    double colpos = chart1.Series[colinfo.colptf].Points.First(x => x.XValue == colinfo.coldate.ToOADate()).YValues[0];
                    addpoint(colinfo.coldate, colpos, colinfo.colstring, chart1.Series["Service dates"]);
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Whats the code you have?

Comment: Are you using Ms Pie Charts?

Comment: I just added the codes to my questions. The `chart1.Series[colinfo.colptf]` is a spline curve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```
var collection = chart1.Series.Select(series => series.Points.Where(point => point.XValue == 0).ToList()).ToList();
```

This will get you a list of series with all points that are at the specified X coordinate.

If you want all the datapoints in 1 list you can now use

```
List<DataPoint> points = new List<DataPoint>();
collection.ForEach(series => series.ForEach(points.Add));
```

Getting the Y value from a DataPoint is simply using YValues, which returns an array of Y values. I assume you only assign 1 Y value to each point, so you can just take the 1st index, which is [0].

So getting the 1st points 1st Y value would be:

```
double yVal = points[0].YValues[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
Could you show me how to proceed to get the Y-value? I'm so new to C#.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my codes and solved the problem. I was really confused because C# allows multiple Y-values to be assigned to a single point though.

Comment: Yes, this is indeed possible. It is used for example a range series where you wanna display Minimum and Maximum values for each X point (for example a chart displaying the lowest and highest temperatures in a country per day)