# Read graph and display output of Y value when user type X value in textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, textbox, regression

Hi i have a regression forecasting graph with x axis and y axis for users.
I want to add a function whereby user type the x value input in a textbox, then the y value output of the graph will be shown.

example x value input: 150, y output will auto display

Is there any way to do that? I am using ASP.NET C#

Comment: Add more details. What component you use for draw graph. And what are you already done?

Comment: I have the graph output after doing regression calculations. The graph have x and y axis shown as in the link. http://s1248.photobucket.com/user/Vannessa_Low/media/reg%20graph_zps0kks9fm6.png.html
Now I want to add a textbox whereby user input a X Value from the graph and will display Y Value.@Sergio

Comment: Here you go http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33778487/get-y-value-of-a-graph-in-c-sharp

Comment: does this code include a textbox where user can type X value (mileage) and system will display Y Value (Sales Price) ? @Sergio

Comment: I thought it's not a problem to place 2 textboxes (for input x and ouput Y) 1 button (to start code) on Form and additional code `var x=Convert.ToInt32(textbox1.text);` If you expect "Ready to copy-paste code" you are wrong.

Comment: Any references for me to refer? Would appreciate it, thanks! As i am new to coding... @Sergio